# "delete_at" Method Deletes Only Even Array Elements

Tags: arrays, ruby

Why does this code delete only even elements within the array?  I would expect the for loop to iterate through each value, 0 through 3, and delete each element one at a time.  But it is only deleting a[0] and a[2].  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance--

```
a=%w(ant bat cat dog)
puts a.inspect #output: ["ant", "bat", "cat", "dog"]

for k in (0..3)
    a.delete_at(k)
end

puts a.inspect #output: ["bat", "dog"]
```

UPDATE--

Thank you for your responses; I see what I was doing now. In order to delete each element of the array, the Array method 'shift' would be appropriate. For example:

```
for each in (0..3)
    a.shift
    print a
end
```

This would shift the first element out of the array, and move each subsequent element forward one cell.  Thank you for the recommendation to use 'each'--I can see that it is the preferred syntax.

UPDATE 2--

Would the following section of code be more representative of proper ruby syntax?

```
(0..3).to_a.each do
    a.shift
    p a
end
```

And Thanks to Glenn for the suggestions on deleting contents of an array.

Comment: Your update code is not written in the Ruby way. `each` is an iterator over an array, as in `[1,2,3].each{ |n| p n }`, not a variable for a `for` loop.

Comment: "Would the following section of code be more representative of proper ruby syntax?" Actually, no, because it doesn't work. Did you try running the code, either as a script or by typing it into IRB?

Comment: Yes; I've tried it in IRB and in a .rb and it works both ways.  I used the same array as in the previous example.  It should just delete all four elements, leaving an empty array.  What do you suggest as an alternative?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use Fixnum#times: `4.times { p a.shift }`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because when you delete element 0 element 1 would be element 2 of the original array.

```
Initially:
[ant, bat, cat, dog]

a.delete_at[0] => ant
[bat, cat, dog]

go to next element -> 1

a.delete_at[1] => cat
[bat, dog]

go to next element -> 2
a.delete_at[2] => nil (out of range)

go to next element -> 3
a.delete_at[3] => nil
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you are deleting the array in place, and the third time the execution enter the loop, your array is shorter than the value of `k`.

Try to execute

```
a=%w(ant bat cat dog)
puts a.inspect #output: ["ant", "bat", "cat", "dog"]

for k in (0..3).to_a
  p k
  a.delete_at(k)
  p a
end

puts a.inspect #output: ["bat", "dog"]
```

Here's the output

```
0
["bat", "cat", "dog"]
1
["bat", "dog"]
2
["bat", "dog"]
3
["bat", "dog"]
```

When `k` is `2`, you are trying to delete the element at index `2` but your array is only composed by 2 elements with indexes 0 and 1.

PS. Avoid using `for`. Use `each` instead, is "more Ruby-oriented".

Answer (score 2):

Well, Firas and Simone have answered your stated question, but in case what you really wanted to know was how to do this deletion effectively, you can delete all elements from an array with:

```
a.clear
```

and you can delete a range of elements with

```
a.slice!(0..3)
```

No need to iterate in either case.